# Can a Way of the Open Hand monk's Open Hand Technique prevent Legendary Action reactions?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, monk, reactions, rise-of-tiamat

Tiamat can take a Legendary Actions at the end of each turn, and I believe these were listed as reactions. Could an Open Hand Monk's Open Hand Technique prevent these legendary actions entirely?

Per the [Way of the Open Hand monk](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#WayoftheOpenHand)'s [Open Hand Technique](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#OpenHandTechnique-256) feature:

> Whenever you hit a creature with one of the attacks granted by your Flurry of Blows, you can impose one of the following effects on that target:
>
> - [...]
> - It can’t take reactions until the end of your next turn.

If that is possible, that interpretation seems overpowered - unless the Legendary Actions are NOT reactions (I may be remembering this incorrectly), or the reactions are treated differently because they're Legendary Actions rather than normal Reactions.

Answer (score 22):

### Legendary actions are not reactions

The text for legendary actions follows this format:

> [The monster] can take 3 Legendary Actions, choosing from the options below. Only one legendary action can be used at a time, and only at the end of another creature's turn. Spent legendary Actions are regained at the start of each turn.

There is no mention of a Legendary Action constituting a reaction, therefore Open Hand Flurry of Blows cannot prevent them.

Comment: Also, if Legendary Actions were reactions, creature with multiple Legendary Actions (like a [Lich](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/lich)) would only be able to use one per turn. (which would be weird in term of game design)

Answer (score 8):

### No, because Legendary Actions are not Reactions

[Legendary Actions](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#LegendaryActions) are unique to each creature. The general rules do not specify another kind of action - they are their own category. What's important is that they take place outside the creature's normal turn order.

> A legendary creature can take a certain number of special actions--called legendary actions--outside its turn. Only one legendary action option can be used at a time and only at the end of another creature's turn. A creature regains its spent legendary actions at the start of its turn. It can forgo using them, and it can't use them while incapacitated or otherwise unable to take actions. If surprised, it can't use them until after its first turn in the combat.

Furthermore, if they were reactions, a creature would be limited to one per turn. Typical creatures have three Legendary Actions per turn, which would make it impossible to use them all if they were reactions.

That said, creatures' statblocks present **Actions**, special **Reactions**, and (when available) **Legendary Actions** under separate headings.

For example:

- [Bandit Captain](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/bandit-captain) has *Multiattack*, *Scimitar*, and *Dagger* under **Actions**, with *Parry* listed separately under **Reactions**.
- [Adult Black Dragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/adult-black-dragon) doesn't happen to have any special **Reactions**, and lists **Actions** and **Legendary Actions** separately.